Browser's behavior UTF-8 page with extra character like U+FFFE (ERROR by ajax) XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
We are developing some JSF web applications with PrimeFaces.
It is possible in inputText to copy/paste text with a non UTF-8 character like `` (Here is the character) and save the page. But there is an error in the rendered HTML:

Error: Forbidden code point U+fffe.

The browser doesn't show (hide) the error, it shows the non UTF-8 character (works like in a normal case)!
But, after this page will be sent from the server to the browser in an Ajax response, the browser shows an error in the console! And the user can see the error!
Console message:

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

What is the best way to handle this error?
I have a lot of bad ideas. :)

Validate input before save!

Client side with Javascript can be general, but not secure.
Replace bad characters to '' can cause misunderstanding by user. There are a lot of bad characters which are like right-accented characters.
I can make a validator for JSF, but I should register it to all inputText components one by one.


Perhaps I can search the Javascript what parses Ajax responses and patch it.


'Minimal' reproduction:
Github link

Download the source
mvn clean package
download wildfly 32.0.1.Final
copy the war from project's target to wildfly/standalone/deployments
start wildfly
http://localhost:8080/utf8/main.xhtml
After copy paste the bad character and click the button, its failed.

I think, the main problem is that Ajax uses XML. And there are a lot of characters in UTF-8 that aren't valid in XML.
How can I check my string fast in Java if there are any invalid characters?
Some other happenings
There are some strange behavior. U+0002 character is removed by jsf writer.

I type U+0002 and click the button
Server side bean property was set.
But the renderResponse phase the Html writer logic has removed this character.

With U+FFFE character is other. I wrote a validator and it throws ValidatorException, but by the renderResponse Phase U+FFFE character appeared.
I think this mojarra bug can be very identical bug:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4516

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

I made my reproduction with wildfly and primefaces.

That looks like a BOM, which should appear in UTF8

(U+FFFE,  *Undefined*) vs. (U+FEFF,  Zero Width No-Break Space aka Byte order mark)?

"non UTF-8 character" - there is no such thing.  UTF-8 is just an encoding of Unicode. What you really mean is a "non Unicode character", and indeed U+FFFE is undefined in Unicode, but it is completely encodable in UTF-8 as bytes 0xEF 0xBF 0xBE. Also, U+FFFE is an illegal character in XML, the spec is very explicit about exactly which Unicode characters are allowed: "any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF". So simply filter them out of your string.

I've reproduced it. The problem is 2-fold. This is indeed a bug in Mojarra which in turn exposed another bug in PrimeFaces Ajax handler. I've created a new issue in Mojarra side: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/5464.

I think this mojarra bug can be very identical bug:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4516

Yes indeed. I've fixed a similar issue a couple of years ago for the Mojarra implementation, however it concerned a different unicode range.
You can for the time being work around it by using MyFaces instead of Mojarra (I've confirmed that it works fine in MyFaces), or by using Standard Faces Ajax instead of PrimeFaces Ajax as follows:
<p:commandButton value="Click" action="#{hello.ajax}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</p:commandButton>


That said,

a non UTF-8 character

if it really wasn't a UTF-8 character (the U stands for Unicode), it wouldn't have been listed in a website dedicated to Unicode characters ... ;)
Unrelated to the concrete problem, I noticed that the XHTML template in your reproducer https://github.com/halcsi19790320/ajax-utf8-problem/blob/main/src/main/webapp/main.xhtml has a lot of unnecessary tags/attributes which you most probably tried to use to fix the problem.
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html ...accept-charset="utf-8">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </h:head>

I can assure that none of these are relevant. The XML prolog is unnecessary for Facelets as well as the average IDE. The XHTML doctype is unnecessary if the client ultimately retrieves a plain HTML page. The legacy accept-charset attribute is ignored by modern browsers (last one which took it serious was Internet Explorer). The <meta http-equiv> is ignored when the HTML page is served via http(s):// protocol instead of via e.g. file://.  The following HTML5 template contains less noise and works just fine:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ...>
    <h:head>

    </h:head>

See also JavaServer Faces 2.2 and HTML5 support, why is XHTML still being used and the KISS principle.

Thanks, the other remarks too. Jakarta, faces HtmlUtils cut lot of non-printable charaters i think there can be resolve better. Not? The 'bad' chars are just u+FFFE and u+FFFF? Or are there any?

I thougth a lot of, what can be better solution before prime/jsf patch...   1. Converter what cut all input theese non-xml characters or 2. default-Validator + a filter like by mojarra bug what remove theese chars from partial response?

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/12331

This is in the end indeed a bug in Mojarra. See updated answer.

One last aspect. After this solution Xml invalid useless characters can set to backing beans, entities, db tables from String based input components. I'ts  true theese are removed from partial response, but after save , ajax get and ajax post theese characters are removeded invisible from server(second save remove them). If I use a validator, I can't write bad characters in the message, and second save the message vanish( because theese are eliminated). I think the best way handle this a ServletFilter which remove all 'bad' chars from requestMap, or jsf string converter. What is your opinion?

You can use a global Faces string converter for this yes.
